References on Narrow Ring Class Fields
I am in the process of writing my master's thesis about the 2018 article of Darmon and Vonk about a Nonarchimedean approach to a real multiplication theory (https://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Research/69.DV1/paper.pdf). Their main conjecture (Conjecture 3.5, p. 74) makes use of the narrow ring class field $H_\tau$ associated to an order $D_\tau$ which lies in a real quadratic number field. One of my goals is to understand and describe this field.
I am familiar with class field theory, the notions of ring class fields for orders in imaginary quadratic fields, as well as the Hilbert class field and ray class fields. However, I have not yet heard about narrow class groups or narrow ring class fields.
So far, I have looked into many of the authors' former publications and the book by Cox - Primes of the form $p=x^{2} + ny^{2}$ - but I was not able to find a thorough definition. Also, I found another question about the narrow Hilbert class field (What is the Galois group of narrow Hilbert class field over Hilbert class field?) which mentions the book by Kazuya Kato. I have yet to check whether it the source I am looking for.
Can someone point me to a (citable) source that gives

The definition of the narrow ring class field via the narrow ring class group.
If there is a definition via moduli, then that as well.

And preferably some context and motivation such as

What is the relation to other class fields/class groups?
What are applications and what are limitations? (For example, relation of the class group to the form class group, see [Cox] Thm. 7.7 and remark on its real quadratic version p. 112)
Is the narrow version specific for the real quadratic case?

Thanks in advance.
[Cox] D. A. Cox with R. Lipsett, Primes of the form $p=x^{2} + ny^{2}$ - Third Edition with Solutions, AMS Chelsea Publishing, 2022
